# Exporting C++ project to Android - JNI/JavaCPP/Visualgdb

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I am facing a critical issue trying to export my opencv project to android. 
Since all of my code is in opencv (C++ version) under visual studio 2013, i started off looking into JNI. I ended up realizing that JNI works good when we export C stuff as name mangling is turned off. Does this affect my C++ code? I think it should as name mangling has to be there for C++ class functions.

Then I found out about JavaCPP. This seemed more promising but the extra overhead its Pointer logic seems strange to get my head around and extra build steps to create .so files.

And finally, read about Visualgdb. Though seems to be in trial, but with my liking for Visual studio, looks reasonable.

Can someone guide my which way I have to follow to translate/bind my code in android so that I  can export my c++ classes? Does plain JNI have a real issue with C++ code and no problems with C? OR do I go for JavaCPP or visualgdb?

You valuable comments will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can use JNI on your c++ code, I'm using it. But you should only use JNI if you want to write all your code in c++ and want java to use that exact c++ code in java side. And for that you should export all functions in your public API. And I must say, passing through custom objects such as `Mat`, `Rect`, etc is not a very easy problem, also debugging is not also straight forward. I suggest you to use [OpenCV Java](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html) and port your code to Java.

Good luck!